# I tried changing the formula a few times, and I couldn't get the data to complete beyond row 47

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

The formula checks if the cell in column A is empty. If not, searches the "Zones and Regions" sheet for values ​​based on the specified criteria and returns the corresponding value in column C. If the cell in column A is empty, returns an empty string

The problem is that it is not taking the data beyond row 47
my current formula:

=SI($A2="";""; INDICE('Zonas y regiones'!$C$3:$C$55;SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO('Zonas y regiones'!$D$57:$AP$109;'Zonas y regiones'!$D$3:$AP$55;$C2;'Zonas y regiones'!$D$111:$AP$163;$D2)))

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OPl7kG_FP4kV6J3GMn_EDNIG5A6SbzGbL8E4QnK31jo/edit?usp=sharing

I tried changing the formula a few times, and I couldn't get the data to complete beyond row 47.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out & see if its givin' out the desired results:*

```js
=map(C2:C;D2:D;lambda(c;d;if(or(c="";d="");;ifna(+filter('Zonas y regiones'!C1:C55;'Zonas y regiones'!A1:A55=c;regexmatch(d;byrow('Zonas y regiones'!D1:AP55;lambda(Σ;textjoin("|";1;Σ)))))))))
```

- *Names like `General Rodríguez` OR `José C. Paz` are slightly different in spelling & not an exact match in the **Zonas y regiones** tab, which you may need to check upon*

[image]